# Should I backup some files if I upgrade 12.04 to 14.04 ?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

Currently I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I would like to upgrade to 14.04. 
Should I backup  some important such as those of the web root folder ? If I would need so,  how should I proceed ?

Comment: No, you do not need to backup anything.

Comment: To be safe, always back up important data.  If you don't have a regular backup scheme, you should likely develop one.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of settings are stored in the hidden folders and files (names starting with `.`, use `Ctrl+H` to see them) in your home directory, so I'd make a backup of your home directory. Furthermore, with `dpkg-query -l > ~/dpkg-list.txt`, you save a list of the programs you installed. You can use it to reinstall these programs after you installed 14.04 on a clean disk/partition.

On the other hand, I believe you can simply update to 14.04 by means of the `Update Manager` without having to worry about the home directory and packages.

This question is a duplicate of `http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu` by the way.